# Ansible syntax check for undefined variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook like :
**myplaybook.yml**

```
---
- name: call another playbook
  hosts: 127.0.0.1

- include: "{{name}}-playbook.yml"
  when: name is defined
```

Here I am passing the 'name' variable from cli as --extra-vars

It is working fine. But while trying to check the syntax with below command its giving error saying **name is undefined**

```
Ansible-playbook --syntax myplaybook.yml
```

Any ideas on how to handle it ?

Comment: Why not pass the name for the syntax check also with `--extra-vars`?

Comment: Actually I can't do it. The syntax check is doing by other system where I have no control. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What syntax do you want to check? If you have many playbooks like `name1-playbook.yml` and `name2-playbook.yml`, how is Ansible supposed to guess all the names and test all of them?

If you want to test just one of them, make default value for `name`, like:

```
- include: "{{ name | default('name1') }}-playbook.yml"
```